# API Call to validate or lint AMPScript prior to send

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

We are currently accepting user input to define messages to send via ExactTarget. It seems like in the case that there is an error in the user's AMPScript, ExactTarget's API doesn't complain, "sends" the message, and comes back with a response saying everything is ok.

Somewhere in their asynchronous queue, ET attempts to parse the user defined AMPScript, and fails, causing the entire send to fail after they've already told us that everything went fine.

Is there anyway to validate or lint the user defined AMPScript through ET's API, SOAP or REST, so we can avoid this scenario?

As far as I know, the only way to do this is to try a Send Preview of the message in question, but this isn't usually possible, since we wouldn't have access to the user's ET account.

Answer (score 0):

I've not actually done what I'm going to recommend, but have a look at the [ET SOAP object page](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/objects/) , specifically at ContentValidation, ContentValidationTaskResult, and ContentValidationResult.  Between those three objects, I think you can validate the email.  Otherwise, you could put the AMPscript content in a ContentArea, then create a dummy landing page with the same content area and then go look at the landing page.  Some AMPscript is email specific, and some landing page specific so this may not work, but will work in like 80% of cases.

Comment: Just by looking at the docs, it seems more like those objects are for spam validation, and not necessarily AMPScript validation. I could be wrong though, I haven't been able to implement those yet. Either way, spam validation would be another thing to check for in these cases.